# phonegap vs objective-c web-kit

Tags: iphone, cordova, webkit

Can somebody tell me what are pros and cons when developing with phonegap or objective-c and web-kit. In other words, if you want to develop (html,css,js) based application is it better to develop it in phonegap or in objective-c with

Comment: There's a million other discussions on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

First, google "Native vs web-app". There are several good guides and comparisons out there, and much of what you will do in phonegap is in the web-app domain. The pros with using web-technology is that it is easier to port to other platforms, it also lets you use HTML, CSS and Javascript some Apache declarations and other snacks that probably will be relatively stable in the years to come instead of learning Objective-C, Java and a lot of APIs. One of the great things about native apps is speed (perhaps not the biggest issue for most applications), it is also some functionality which can't be achieved through the browser or web-app runtime (that's where Phonegap tries to fill the gap). Also, the developers of each of the various mobile-OS make a lot of convenient shortcuts and tools which you perhaps would have to emulate through web-technologies.